# Row span is not working as i expected

Tags: html, css, web

I want to achieve this:
[image]

and I did these with `<td>` tag but only col span is working correctly

```
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>hu043</td>
                <td>7903</td>
                <td>90df78</td> 
              </tr>
            <tr>

            <tr>

                <td colspan="4" rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>

            </tr>
```

Comment: You have one `<tr>`without closing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of rowspan is to span existing rows, like you are spanning existing columns in your example.

If you will add some rows below, you will see it.

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr style='height:20px;'></tr>
<tr style='height:20px;'></tr>
<tr style='height:20px;'></tr>
```